# php magician resize - display image instead of saving to the folder

Tags: php, image, resize, gd, image-resizing

I'm trying to resize the image and display it on the browser. I'm using php_image_magician to resize the image from database. it resized the image succesfully. I want to display the image instead of saveImage (`$magicianObj -> saveImage('img.jpeg');`). How do I echoed this image properly `echo "<img src='".???."' />";`

```
require_once(PAGEINC.'php_image_magician.php');
$magicianObj = new imageLib("http://localhost".$newsfirstimgpath);
$magicianObj -> resizeImage(50, 50, 'crop');
$magicianObj -> saveImage('img.jpeg');
```

Comment: did you mean
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo(file_get_contents("img.jpeg"));

Comment: I want to display image instead of saveimage. I don't want to save the resized images to folder

Comment: did you try $im = $magicianObj -> resizeImage(50, 50, 'crop') and then header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Output the image
imagejpeg($im);

Comment: What about saving the image in a temporary folder, and do echo `<img src="tempfolder/imageXXX.jpg" />`?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `displayImage` function of the library as follows:

```
$magicianObj->displayImage('jpeg',100); // first param tells display as jpeg and second specifies the quality of the image
```

you can find other available functions in [this link](https://github.com/Oberto/php-image-magician/blob/master/php_image_magician.php) check line no 2529 for the `displayImage` reference

**Edit**

Add following function just above the displayImage function in the `php_image_magician.php`

```
public function getImageSrc($fileType = 'jpg') {
    ob_start();
    if (!is_resource($this->imageResized)) { if ($this->debug) { die('saveImage: This is not a resource.'); }else{ die(); }}

    switch($fileType)
    {
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg':
            imagejpeg($this->imageResized, NULL, $imageQuality);
            break;
        case 'gif':
            imagegif($this->imageResized);
            break;
        case 'png':
            // *** Scale quality from 0-100 to 0-9
            $scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);

            // *** Invert qualit setting as 0 is best, not 9
            $invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;

            imagepng($this->imageResized, NULL, $invertScaleQuality);
            break;
        case 'bmp':
            die('bmp file format is not supported.');
            break;
        default:
            // *** No extension - No save.
            die('file extension not supported.');
            break;
    }
    $response = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return 'data:image/'.$fileType.';base64,' . base64_encode( $response );
}
```

And use following code to echo image:

```
echo '<img src="'.$magicianObj->getImageSrc('jpeg').'" />';
```

Comment: imagejpeg(): Filename cannot be empty 2519 line error

Comment: looks like there is bug in the library, you can do one thing, change `imagejpeg($this->imageResized, '', $imageQuality);` to `imagejpeg($this->imageResized, NULL, $imageQuality);` in side `displayImage` function and do this also for other similar functions like for `imagepng` also.